# Restrict number of selections and insert selected data into an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, filter, restrict

I have 15 list items. I allow user to pick only 5 out of them. Then I put this info into the array and submit to the server.

```
<li><a href="#" id="item1" class="select">Item One</a></li> ... etc.
```

Then I use this code to toggle class of selected items

```
function SelectPrizes (){
$('a.select').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Choose prize' ? 'Selected' : 'Choose prize');
    return false;
});
}
```

My question is, how to allow only 5 selections and add only selected items to an array by ID.

I understand that I can filter by hasClass('selected'), but I can't figure out the right syntax for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your three questions:

Allowing 5 selections: Make sure the length of `$('a.select.selected')` doesn't exceed your limit of 5:

```
if ( $('a.select.selected').length < 5 ) {
    // Does not exceed, so we can add...
}
```

Add only selected items to array: just add only those items with the class 'selected':

```
$('a.select.selected').each(function(){
    // Add to array
});
```

The syntax of hasClass('selected') as Mr. Disappointment suggested:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {

}
```

The solution of Mr. Disappointment will work if you allow the user to select more than 5 items and then select just any 5 of them.

Also, a suggestion to improve your html. I assume the li items have a ul parent. Set the class 'select' to this ul parent and use the selector: $('ul.select li a').click().

I've put this all together in a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5b8aj/6/

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much, I have rewritten my code, mine was kinda nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`slice(start, end)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get a specific number of results from the selection, starting from the specified index.

```
var results = $("a.select").slice(0, 5);
```

The second part of your question can be answered with a conditional check:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check following value for submission decision about whether 5 elements are selected are not -

```
$('a.select[class*="selected"]').length==5
```